# Where can I find the QtQuickCompiler generated C++ files on Linux?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-quick

I am using the [QtQuickCompiler](http://doc.qt.io/QtQuickCompiler/) to compile my QML files, with `qmake` project file.

I'd like to check what the C++ looks like but in the build-directory there is only the usual files (.cpp for the resources, the executable, and the object files .o).

Where are generated the .cpp files from the QML before being compiled as object files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are in a hidden directory inside the build-directory named `.qtquickcompiler/`.